# Wood vs Steel framing for moving house

Tags: walls

I'm trying to make a tiny (3 x 1.6 x 2 meters or 9.8 x 5.2 x 6 feet) shack on a trailer that can legally be dragged at 100km/h aka 62 mph.

I am curious about the frontal force of the wind at this speed (or maybe 115km/h - 70mph winds in windy conditions).

My framing would either be 2x2" wood or 40mm square steel tubing with a 2mm wall thickness.

Which would be better to support the force of the wind as far structure strength goes, or is that not something I should be concerned with?

Comment: The framing doesn't create the shear (diagonal) rigidity. The sheathing does.

Comment: If you are driving 62 mph, and you design for a 70 mph load ("in windy conditions") that only lets you drive into an 8 mph headwind. Is that a limitation you are willing to accept?

Comment: @isherwood Actually, both the framing and the sheathing create the resistance in shear. 2x2 material is not rigid enough to keep sheathing “in line” for large spans (4’x8’ areas). It might be ok for smaller areas (2’x4’ or so). The Code allows maximum shear values based on framing size (and nail size and spacing) and sheathing (material and thickness).

Comment: I vote for steel stronger than wood.  Steel tubing with  plywood or OSB sheathing.

Comment: 2x2 walls which are sheathed inside and out will handle modest highway speeds just fine, assuming proper fastening. Almost any fishhouse or RV trailer is built the same way.

Comment: Since this will end up being a popularity contest I'm voting to close as opinion-based. "Better" is usually subjective. In this case, either will work and it comes down to price and building preferences.

Comment: the steel tubing is much stronger. of course, if it faces too much force, the damage is worse than it would be to wood, which bends without crumpling.

Comment: Yeah, I might be expressing myself a bit off. I do plan on having at least 8mm thick wood planks or OSB as sheathing on both sides, but was wondering if the frame itself would support such a load

Comment: Another thing to mention is that I am subject to European laws, not the American building systems, the surface is at most 50 sqft anyway and it's not a plan to build a "tiny house" but instead a trailer that can be used for 1 weekend at a time every now and then in the spring/ summer